# Angular 5 with RxDB (idb adaptor) threws Uncaught TypeError: winningRev is not a function error when creating database

Tags: angular-cli, indexeddb, angular5, pouchdb, pouchdb-adapter-localstorage

I am using Angualr Cli 1.6.5(Angular 5.2.0) with RxDB 7.3.2 and pouchdb-adapter-idb 6.4.2.

When I tried to create/connect to the database i am getting this errors:

```
zone.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: winningRev is not a function
    at insertDoc (index.es.js:370)
    at nextDoc (index.es.js:449)
    at eval (index.es.js:452)
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at processDocs (index.es.js:426)
    at idbProcessDocs (index.es.js:330)
    at checkDone (index.es.js:354)
    at IDBRequest.readMetadata [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYsuccess] (index.es.js:364)
    at IDBRequest.wrapFn (zone.js:1166)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
index-browser.es.js:486 Database has a global failure DOMException: Uncaught exception in event handler.
```

This is the function i am calling from:

```
async getRxDB() {
    this.rx_db = await RxDB.create({
        name: 'testdb',
        adapter: 'idb',
        multiInstance: false
    });
    console.log(this.rx_db);

    await this.rx_db.collection({name: 'fork', schema: TestDBSchema});
}
```

The database schema:

```
const TestDBSchema = {
    'title': 'test schema',
    'version': 0,
    'description': 'describes a simple task',
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
      'name': {
          'type': 'string',
          'primary': true
      }
    }

};
```

and i simply called this function in a component as such:

```
constructor(private databaseService: DatabaseService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.databaseService.getRxDB();
}
```

I have searched on the internet but couldn't find a similar issue.
Does any encounter this error with the similar settings?

**Update**
The link @[lossleader](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269466/lossleader) provide does work, thank

Comment: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/7054

Comment: Thanks this does provide a workaround solution for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PouchDB 6.4.2 shipped with [broken es modules](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/7054) due to a bug in the version of rollup it was transpiled with. (The transpiler bug removed the `as Y` from `import X as Y` syntax without renaming local X variables to prevent shadowing.)

PouchDB 6.4.3 has now been published to npm and was transpiled with rollup 0.55.1 which [fixes the bug](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/commit/0c3f4f990874bd9982413469228eefe3766f16fb) so updating should resolve the problem.